# Flutter: Width of DropDown menu independent of Button size

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

I have two `DropDownButton`s in one Row.

```
  DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
    child: DropdownButton(
      isExpanded: true,
      value: item,
      items: widget.items.map((item) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: item, 
          child: Text(
            item.toString(),
          );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: widget.onChanged,
      selectedItemBuilder: (context) {
        return widget.items.map((item) {
          return Align(
            child: Text(
              item.toString(),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          );
        }).toList();
      }
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

Is there a way to stretch the width of the menu instead of keeping it the size of the button?

**Edit:**

[Example: Dart pad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=49844704216a0ad1c3512a491330e3d2) (Thanks to @Diwyansh; Dropdown only uses half the width of the UI, not entire)

Comment: You want to stretch options width?

Comment: @Diwyansh I don't understand your question, sry :) What do you mean? I want to stretch the expanded menu width to either text length or max screen width

Comment: Basically you want the dropdownitems to stretch to available width? And there's la error in your code also.

Comment: Yes, just stretch the menu (items) and keep the original button width.

Comment: Try answer once may it work for you.

Comment: your above code is working fine my side I think the problem isn't ni this code may be and other widget is causing the issue to cross check you can run your above code with DartPad you'll see that the code is clean

Comment: Maybe a surrounding Expanded may affect it? Since the widget is Row(children: [Expanded: DropDownButton, Expanded: DropDownButton))...

Comment: Actually I have also tried that scenario with your code Row with two Expanded and DropdownButton inside Expanded but still can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: can you show me a DartPad example? Maybe I can get it broken... But I don't know how to start there :D

Comment: check this https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=49844704216a0ad1c3512a491330e3d2

Comment: Thanks. For me it shows exactly my problem: The expanded menu items field is only half the width of the entire screen. It has the same size as the button. I want to have it filled the entire width (going over both Dropdowns)

Comment: I don't think there's any property to do this but may be we can get it by applying some trick.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I've fixed this and added more customization in [DropdownButton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2). By default dropdown menu will take button width but you can change it too if you want.  Dropdownbutton2 is based on Flutter's core DropdownButton with more options you can customize to your needs.